# Is the concept of equal subsets a fallacy?

Tags: math, set, logic, discrete-mathematics

A definition of subset that I found on the internet([In this web, 2nd point 3th paragraph](http://math.siomax.ru/Sets.html)) and in a book([set theory related topics by lipschutz, Page 3 - Def. 1-1](https://math10batch.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/set-theory-related-topics-by-lipschutz.pdf)) says or implies that:

```
A=B If at the same time A⊂B and B⊂A;
```

This would imply that A is contained in B, but it would also imply that B is contained in A.

Wouldn't this be a fallacy as demonstrated in Russell's paradox?

I imagine it would be something like that, it's this right?
[This Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpPj.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: "A⊂B" does not mean A is contained in B, it means A is a subset of B

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "contains" can be used in two very different ways for a set: "contains as a member" and "contains as a subset", so I would suggest avoiding it or being very clear which one you mean. I think the second one is less common to use "contains" for, but it still happens.

It's true that A can't be a member of B when B is a member of A (but not really related to Russell's paradox); but A can be a subset of B and B a subset of A. Just consider A={1} and B={1}. Then every member of A (i.e. 1) is a member of B, so A is a subset of B. And vice versa.

> I imagine it would be something like that, it's this right? This Img

This would be if B is a *proper* subset of A (that is, a subset of A but not equal to A) and A is a proper subset of B.

Answer (score 0):

A set X is contained in set Y if every element of X is in Y.
So, even if X is equal to Y, X is considered to be contained in Y.

At this point, it will be clear that if X is contained in Y and Y is contained in X as well in the same time, they should be equal.

Comment: Saying that X is contained in Y and that Y is contained in X would not be redundant, as in this picture??

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpPj.png)

Comment: @Jet1224 Yes. First of all, sets have fixed elements. They don’t change size.

Comment: if they have elements defined and they don't change their size, then does it mean that X contains Y, but Y couldn't contain X at the same time? And putting it into practice, would it be so?

[Link](https://i.imgur.com/BQY888C.png)

Comment: X ⊂ Y means that all elements of X are the elements of Y and nothing else.
The author of text of your first link just plays with the words.

Comment: This question was closed and your answer was timed prior to the closure timing. I've voted to keep your answer as I don't think you should be penalised due to a decision taken after you've answered.